# Setup AWS IAM instace role policy to GetObject based only on bucket policy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam, aws-policies

I'm not able to change IAM role policy in our corporate environment. So I want to be able to change role's permissions to S3 based on bucket policy. I want to setup AWS IAM instance role to have Allow on "s3:GetObject" based on this bucket policy.

I have this in my bucket policy:

```
{
        "Sid": "tag-based",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::XY:role/testing"
        },
        "Action": "s3:*",
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::bucket1/path1/*",
            "arn:aws:s3:::bucket1/path1"
        ]
    },
```

And I want something like this in my IAM role inline policy -> To have allow only for resources which have TagKey equal to 'SG':

```
{
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "s3:PutObject",
            "s3:GetObject",
            "s3:DeleteObject",
            "s3:PutObjectAcl"
        ],
        "Resource": "<HOW TO SETUP IT ONLY FOR RESORUCES WHICH HAVE TAG KEY 'SG?'>",
        "Condition": {
            "ForAllValues:StringEquals": {
                "aws:TagKeys": [
                    "SG"
                ]
            }
        }
    }


Is this right way to achieve it?
```

Comment: "Is this right way to achieve it?" - try and see, and tell us if you get any errors or issues.

Answer (score 1):

S3 support for [Authorization based on tags is partial](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_aws-services-that-work-with-iam.html) that means not all the operations supports tag based conditions. Which is further mentioned [here as well](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/service-authorization/latest/reference/list_amazons3.html#amazons3-resources-for-iam-policies).

As far as the calls you mentioned in your policy how they work with tags are described [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/object-tagging.html#tagging-apis)

`GetObject` and `PutObect` revolves around `x-amz-tag-count header`. Which further requires another permission named [GetObjectTagging](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_GetObjectTagging.html)

> "<HOW TO SETUP IT ONLY FOR RESORUCES WHICH HAVE TAG KEY 'SG?'>"

There is no such clause for resources specifically, you can find the same in the above linked page under the section named `Resource types defined by Amazon S3`

In summary what you are trying to achieve simply in terms of `tag` based authorization might not fully work as you expect.